# How to prove that for flows in Vector fields the statement: $\theta_t \circ \theta_s =\theta_{t+s}$ holds

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

I am studying smooth manifolds from the book of John Lee and I am struck on this deduction.

This question and image is from page 209 of the book.

[image]

In 2nd para I  understand that by uniqueness of integral curve we have $\theta^q (t)= \theta^p(t+s)$.

> But I am not able to understand how if we translate that into a statement about the maps $\theta_t$, it becomes $\theta_t \circ \theta_s(p)= \theta_{t+s} (p)$?

Can you please tell how should I deduce this?

Comment: Integral curves solve a smooth autonomous differential équation. The flow property (in the sense of dynamical system, or group (semi-group pro[perty) follows from uniqueness of solutions to differential equations with a given initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start from $\theta^{(q)}(t) = \theta^{(p)}(t+s)$ if $q = \theta^{(p)}(s)$. Then, it is just a matter of notations :

$$ \theta_t \circ \theta_s(p) = \theta_t \left( \theta^{(p)}(s) \right) = \theta_t(q) = \theta^{(q)}(t) = \theta^{(p)}(t+s) = \theta_{t+s}(p) $$

where I use that $\theta^{(x)}(u) = \theta_u(x)$ for every $x \in M$ and every $u \in \mathbb{R}$ (or a suitable interval $I$ on which the flow is well-defined).